# how to register a spring cloud task java jar into spring data flow kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-task

I am just curious about the register method on the spring data flow kubernetes document. why do we use --uri a docker image at the same time we also use --metadata a jar. Can we just use one of them to register?

app register --type source --name time --uri docker://springcloudstream/time-source-rabbit:1.3.1.RELEASE --metadata-uri maven://org.springframework.cloud.stream.app:time-source-rabbit:jar:metadata:1.3.1.RELEASE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The metadata jar is not required to register the app, however, you want to enable properties help such as auto-complete, list available properties (app info), etc. The metadata jar is packaged separately as an optimization to provide this information during stream/task creation without having to download the entire app which normally happens during deployment.